# Sort by date the column in datatable

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using jsf2.2 primefaces 6.0 and i'm trying to sort the datatable column by date as presented in the figure: 
[image]

I used sortBy" attribute in order to sort the date column but nothing happend.
If there is a working solution on primefaces component "p:column" or directly sorting the date from the liste using java code would be appriciated(Rq: i'm a beginner programmer).

Xhtml code:

```
<p:column headerText="Date dépot"  sortBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{a.dateDeDepot}" >
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                                timeZone="GMT+1:00" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
```

The java Bean code:

```
public List<Demande> getAllDemandes() {
        allDemandes = demandeServicesLocal.findAllDemandes();
        return allDemandes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Demande> getAllDemandes() {
    allDemandes = demandeServicesLocal.findAllDemandes();
    Collections.sort(allDemandes, new Comparator<Demande>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Demande d1, Demande d2)
        {
            return d1.getdate().compareTo(d2.getdate());//use the name specified in the pojo class for getting the date in the place of 'getdate'
        }
    });
    return allDemandes;
}
```

> both ascending and descending order sorting can be done by changing return type.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not match asked, how to add a button to sort the table ascending and descending from the view or through using a calendar primefaces component.